# How do I edit an Azure app registration from Java

Tags: java, azure

I have a Java application that needs to update some fields of the manifest.json of an app registration in Azure.

I have already done this from the Linux terminal with the azure-cli tool. I then tried to google for a similar Java SDK to do this but only came up with SDKs that let you authenticate against Azure.

Is there another SDK for my use case or do I have to use some API directly via HTTP?

Comment: When you say 'app registration', what do you mean? A java app deployed to app service host or something?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Management SDK](https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/mgmt).

Sample code:

```java
// skip this if you know the object id
ActiveDirectoryApplication app = azure.accessManagement().activeDirectoryApplications()
        .getByName("<app_name>");

GraphRbacManagementClient client = azure.accessManagement().activeDirectoryApplications().manager().serviceClient();
client.getApplications().patch(
        app.id(),
        (ApplicationUpdateParameters) new ApplicationUpdateParameters()
                .withGroupMembershipClaims(GroupMembershipClaimTypes.ALL));
```

It is a bit convoluted, because technically speaking AAD does not belong to Management. AAD is included in the SDK mainly for RBAC (role-based-access-control) for other resources.